# How can I display `Null` value data on Y Axis using the Primitive dataset format in Chart.js V3.7.0?

Tags: javascript, chart.js, chart.js3

I was wondering if there is a way to display or append `Null` values in [Primitive Dataset](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/general/data-structures.html#primitive).

So far this is a short explanation in code of what my code actually does and how I try to Achieve the same thing, but with no success.

**PHP Code** (*I use php to format some data I have in the correct format according to the* `Primitive dataset documentation`):

```
<?php
    //The Variable below is being appended with data.
    $values .= "$value_I_want_to_append ,";
?> 
// In the end the $values variable looks like this if printed:
   0.456 ,0,424 ,0.223 etc...
```

**Chart's script where I use this variable:**

```
 const data = {
   datasets: [{
      data: [ <? echo $values; ?> ],
   }],
 };
```

**Question**:

How can I append data that is `of type` equal to `Null` on the chart, without the chart breaking?
(By the term breaking, I mean the chart is not displaying values at all when I have atleast one null value).

Thanks in advance for your time and effort. The Library is Called `Chart.js` and the version of the library is `3.7.0`.

Comment: Chart does not break by adding null values, it still shows values: https://jsfiddle.net/Leelenaleee/4w0stLpk/

Comment: Well this is the data I tried to echo in the data variable: ( 0.214 , NULL ,NULL ,NULL ,0.21 , NULL ,NULL ,NULL ,0.447 , NULL ,NULL ,NULL ,0.337 , NULL ,NULL ,NULL ,NULL ,NULL ,NULL ,NULL ,NULL ,NULL ,NULL ,NULL ,NULL ) but this breaks the chart and chart isnt being initialized.

Comment: Is there a way to connect 2 data points with a line, when they have a `null` value in between them?

Comment: Yes, but you will need to use object notation, see my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68863515/8682983

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define `spanGaps: true` on your dataset.

> `spanGaps`: If `true`, lines will be drawn between points with no or `null` data.
>
> For further details, consult the [Line Styling](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/charts/line.html#line-styling) section of the Chart.js documentation.

```js
new Chart('chart', {
  type: 'line',
  data: {
    labels: ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G'],
    datasets: [{
      data: [15, null, 13, 8, null, 9, 10],
      backgroundColor: 'rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5)',
      borderColor: 'rgb(255, 0, 0)',
      tension: 0.2,
      spanGaps: true
    }],
  },
  options: {
    scales: {
      y: {
        beginAtZero: true
      }
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/3.7.0/chart.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="chart"></canvas>
```